# Can someone explain what satisfying a polynomial means in context of linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Deﬁne $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $T(x,y,z) = (x+y,y,2x−2y+2z)$.

Check that $T$ satisﬁes the polynomial $(x−1)^2(x−2)$.

What exactly am I supposed to satisfy here? Is it asking to see $T$ can be a zero of the polynomial?

Comment: Presumably, you mean $T(x,y,z)$

Comment: Probably they want you to verify that $$(T-I)^2(T - 2I) = 0$$

Comment: @mechanodroid: I came to the same conclusion. But isn't the language a bit vague? I just wanted to know, is there any other way to interpret this at all?

Comment: No it means " is a solution of " as mechanodroid said

Comment: I personally do not think it is vague and I think it is a fairly common phrase.

Comment: That is the intended interpretation. Linear transformations from a vector space to itself form what’s called a ring (a setting where you can add and multiply) and in any ring it makes sense to apply a polynomial to an element.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks. Resolved.

Comment: Anyway, it's not very well formulated. You can satisfy an equation, an inequality and the like, but not a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to verify that $(T - I)^2(T-2I) = 0$.

One possible solution:

The characteristic polynomial of $T$ is:

$$\det(T - \lambda I) = \begin{vmatrix}
1 - \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 - \lambda & 0 \\
2 & -2 & 2 - \lambda
\end{vmatrix} = (2-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
1 - \lambda & 1 \\
0 & 1 - \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix} = (1-\lambda)^2(2-\lambda)$$

Therefore, by Hamilton-Cayley's theorem we have $(T - I)^2(T-2I) = 0$.